# Xbox controller does not start

Tags: xbox-360

When I start my Xbox 360 controller with a 3-day old battery the light on the controller turns green, gets dimmer, and then finally disappears (in ~2 secs). Changing the battery fixes the problem. Does anybody else experience this issue or is it just that my controller is old? This problem started 1-2 years after I bought my xbox-360.

**EDIT:** The old battery [at the time of being changed] has >50% battery according to the console and it works on other devices

Comment: Battery has gone corrupt? Or just displaying wrong charge information. Have you tried using different battery pack?

Comment: @LittleHelper I'm Talking about the light surrounding the X button used to start the controller. I haven't used a new battery pack. When I get the controller working (by changing the batteries, switching the positions, etc.) and press the main button, I see the charge info (on the screen) to be >50%. Also, those batteries work with other devices.

Comment: @TimeLord64 The battery has >50% charge and i have used such batteries in other devices. BTW, Mother of timing

Comment: The problem I see with this question is mainly the context. Your having an *electrical* problem with a *game controller*. Ive worked in electrical enough to know that the problem may very well have nothing to do with the fact that you are having the problem with a controller, instead of (for example) a TV remote. I woud like to see pictures of the inside of the battery compartment, and while Im not entirely convinced this is offtopic, I might vote anyway in a couple of days, to get this migrated to electrical (where youll probably have more luck).

Comment: @TimeLord64 the battery compartment is normal with no accidents. This problem had started slowly, when vibration would turn the controller off. But the problem isn't a gap somewhere, otherwise changing the polarity of the batteries would not work.Also thnx for the undownvote :3

Comment: I've had at least 2 controllers that came with play and charge kits (microsoft branded) where the batteries seemed to go bad.  However, using a different rechargeable battery pack or switching to either rechargeable or alkaline AA batteries did not work.  Even having the charge cable attached with the battery pack didn't work.  The only way I could get my controllers to work was to use the charge cable without any batteries, essentially creating a wired controller.

Comment: @ps2goat I had the same issue, after a few years, batteries were simply not an option anymore to play and I had to use the charge cable to connect to the xbox and play wired.

Answer (score 1):

chances are the battery pack is damaged internally causing a short of sorts which is known as internal discharge. With good care a standard nihm rechargable battery will often only last about 3 years before this type of problem becomes an issue. Personally I have found that my charger controller boards go bad before the internal batteries go but you seem to have had the board last longer than your batteries optimum life. if you were to throw the pack on a cement pad a few times to crack the thing open you would find that is all that is inside is two standard nihm batteries the charge controller and the contacts. 
Cheapest solution would be to buy the adapter to simply use your own rechargables...
You may possibly be able to extend the life of the old pack still with a hand full of tricks such as fully discharging the pack and freezing it over night then charging it back up with a low amperage charger....look up rechargable nihm maintenance for more info.

Comment: I looked up but didnt understand anything. I'm not at all into electricals. Also I'm talking about non-rechargable AA Batteries that are put in the controller.